# natbib, hyperref and citation inside a float figure

Tags: hyperref, natbib

I use Lyx and MikTeX 2.9 to write my thesis based on book KOMA-script. Right at the finish I have an error at pdflatex run:

```
Extra }, or forgotten \ endgroup.

<argument> ... \IeC {\c s}i dreapta D=2.9\relax }}
                                              \hyper@linkend 
l.25 ...apta D=2.9\relax }}{32}{figure.caption.25}

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
```

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[romanian]{article}
\usepackage[]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
  bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
  breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\bibstyle@comma{\bibpunct(),a,,}
\newcommand\bibstyle@semicolon{\bibpunct();a,,}
\makeatother
\pretocmd\citet{\citestyle{comma}}\relax\relax
\pretocmd\Citet{\citestyle{comma}}\relax\relax
\pretocmd\citep{\citestyle{semicolon}}\relax\relax
\pretocmd\Citep{\citestyle{semicolon}}\relax\relax

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{centering}
aaaa
\par\end{centering}

\caption{Suprafete fractale Brown-iene obinute cu funcia \emph{r.surf.fractal}
\cite{Wood1996} din GRASS GIS: stanga - D=2.1, centru D=2.5 si dreapta
D=2.9}
\end{figure}


\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}\bibliography{D:/JURNALE/a}

\end{document}
```

The bib entry is:

```
@phdthesis{Wood1996,
author = {Wood, Jo},
booktitle = {Advances in cancer research},
file = {:D$\backslash$:/JURNALE/Bettuzzi\_2009.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0065-230X},
month = jan,
pmid = {19878769},
school = {University of Leicester},
title = {{The geomorphological characterisation of digital elevation models}},
volume = {104},
year = {1996}
}
```

and the [a.bib](http://www.geomorphologyonline.com/a.bib) file.

I use a modification of chicago bibtex style.

While the code contains a lot of optimisation, the error was in when i added the code

```
\newcommand\bibstyle@comma{\bibpunct(),a,,}
\newcommand\bibstyle@semicolon{\bibpunct();a,,}
\makeatother
\pretocmd\citet{\citestyle{comma}}\relax\relax
\pretocmd\Citet{\citestyle{comma}}\relax\relax
\pretocmd\citep{\citestyle{semicolon}}\relax\relax
\pretocmd\Citep{\citestyle{semicolon}}\relax\relax
```

This is required for me to obtain coma and colon separated citations.

The error is localized in relation to some citations included in float figure captions. 
I read it on the web that some times natbib and hyperref does not like each other, and indeed when I comment the code above the document compile.

Any clue regarding this issue would help!
Thanks in advance!

Mihai

Comment: Please use a minimal working example (MWE)/

Comment: Well, I tried that, but my knowledge of LaTeX beside trowing in Lyx code, is limited. What should i include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is missing two pieces:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
```

The first is to get the commands `\citet` and similar ones; the second provides `\pretocmd`. However, patching those commands in that way is wrong, as they are "robust commands".

Do this, instead:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\citet{\citestyle{comma}}{}{}
\xpretocmd\Citet{\citestyle{comma}}{}{}
\xpretocmd\citep{\citestyle{semicolon}}{}{}
\xpretocmd\Citep{\citestyle{semicolon}}{}{}
```

so that the patches will be to the correct internal macro. You still need `natbib`, of course. Loading `etoolbox` is not necessary.

In case `xpatch` is not available in your TeX distribution, you can still do the correct patch:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\expandafter\pretocmd\csname citet \endcsname{\citestyle{comma}}{}{}
```

(similarly for the other three commands).

Comment: Your indication with xpatch works! Natbib is missing cause I added using LyX menu, not as TeX code. Thank you!

Comment: @mihainiculita Please, have a read to the FAQ, particularly [How to ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask)